# Multiple Node Styles

Tags: python, styles, nodes, pydot

According to this page: http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes
Graphviz supports multiple style per Node.

I'm trying to have a rounded box with a red filling. On the page linked, multiple styles are delimited by a comma, so I tried this in Python using [`pydot`](https://pypi.org/project/pydot):

```
graph.add_node( pydot.Node( 'external', shape='box', style='rounded,filled', fillcolor='red' ) )
```

But that throws and error. I also tried delimiting with a space, or passing a list of styles. Couldn't get it to work

Has anyone managed to apply multiple styles to a node?

Answer (score 11):

Just add double quotes like this:

```
style='"rounded,filled"'
```